# How to require javascript model files within the index.js file?

Tags: javascript, module, model, require, innerhtml

I have 2 model files containing a constructor in each, and an index.js file, that I wish to use to insert elements into a HTML file, using innerHTML. I want to use one of the variables from the js model file, however when I try to require the files in the index.js file, the innerHTML file suddenly stops working. Please note, the code in the current `window.onload' function is inserting h1 elements as a test, I will be replacing this with a return value from the constructor, but at the moment, when I require the files, even the h1 insert stops working. Code snippets that I think are relevant can be seen below:

index.js file:

```js
var ToDo = require('../src/toDo.js');
var ToDoList = require('../src/toDoList.js');

window.onload = function() {

         // create a couple of elements in an otherwise empty HTML page
         var heading = document.createElement("h1");
         var heading_text = document.createTextNode("Big Head!");
         heading.appendChild(heading_text);
         document.body.appendChild(heading);
      }
```

Model file 1:

```js
function ToDo(task) {
  this.task = task;
  this.complete = false;
}

module.exports = ToDo;
```

```js
function ToDoList() {
  this.array = [];
}

ToDoList.prototype.add = function(task) {
  this.array.push(task);
};

ToDoList.prototype.popTask = function() {
  var poppedTask = this.array.pop();
  var concat = "<ul><li>";
  var concat2 = "</li></ul>";
  return (concat + poppedTask.task + concat2);
};

module.exports = ToDoList;
```

Comment: What is the innerHTML file?

Comment: innerHTML is a function to modify the html of a node, it's not a file

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` followed by `require not defined.` Im just wondering whether I can use require in this case and whether there is another way of getting the  information into the index.js file?

Comment: the question is which "require" are you expecting? The same require that node uses? or the RequireJS library which you haven't imported. Either way, require is not found. If it's the node one, then you need a tool to compile the files for you. If it's the other one, then you need the library

Comment: Well, node and the browser are different things. You need to use a tool like webpack to package the files together and spit it out compiled.

Comment: ah, no im using the browser! :-) sorry.Yes, I think it is the library I need, require doesnt seem to be supporting in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

`require` is CommonJs feature, and it's not supported by browsers without this library. So you would need to use it in your project if you want modules with require syntax.

**Update**

To use `require` feature, you would need some module loader. There are two very popular that you could check out - **Webpack** or **Browserify**. They both support CommonJS `require` that you are looking for. As for me, I like webpack most, cause it is very powerful out of the box.
To read about their comparison :
https://medium.com/@housecor/browserify-vs-webpack-b3d7ca08a0a9#.lb3sscovr

**RequireJS** is another module loader, but he works not with CommonJs-style modules (`require`). He implements AMD-style modules.
You can check this article to understand how AMD is different from CommonJS: 
https://auth0.com/blog/2016/03/15/javascript-module-systems-showdown/

Comment: sorry, which library?

Comment: @sdawes
Updated answer with more explanation